# Android Studio: You must specify a path to Genymotion folder to use this feature

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I've downloaded and installed the Genymotion emulator plugin via the plugin wizard in Android Studio. I'm running Android Studio on a **Windows** machine.

I'm getting a warning saying that I must provide a path to Genymotion folder:

[image: warning]

Where is this folder located? I can not seem to find it in my Android Studio installation folder.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For windows, the default path is `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`

On a Mac, you will find it here: `/Applications/Genymotion.app`

You have to enter it inside the Android Studio settings, under Genymotion section.

Comment: Since this question is generating a lot of hits, I'd suggest that you include the Mac solution to this problem which can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252690/android-studio-you-must-specify-a-path-to-genymotion-folder-to-use-this-feuture). Basically, the path on a Mac machine seems to be `/Applications/Genymotion.app`

Comment: @eyal-lezmy i tried your path it didn't worked for me, I've downloaded and installed the Genymotion emulator plugin via the Plugin wizard in Android Studio on  Windows and facing same issue, the path i mentioned after locating Genymotion plugin is `C:\Users\android-4\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins\genymotion-idea-plugin-20140326` but failed to configure.

Comment: also tried `C:\Users\android-4\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins\genymotion-idea-plugin-20140326\com\genymobile\genymotion`

Comment: These paths are not the Genymotion software path but the Genymotion Android Studio (IDEA) plugin path. Try to install Genymotion AND VirtualBox from this page: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download#doc the link is "Get Genymotion"

Comment: @eyal-lezmy thank a lot for your concerned responses, i tried it yesterday on my own. :)

Comment: I successfully installed the plugin from Android studio on Mac. But I didn't see any GenyMotion app inside "Applications" folder.

Comment: DOESNT WORK FOR LINUX: Installed Genymotion plugin Android Studio from SDK manager.  Cant get it to run, attempted to enter a folder name but Android Studio responded that  it could not find Genymotion at said location.   See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have installed genymotion and virtual box then provide the link to genymotion location in windows by default is C:/program files/genymobile/genymotion

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if anyone had the same problem but I received this same warning from Android Studio when clicking on the Genymotion Plugin warning me that

> "You must specify a path to genymotion folder to use this feature"

The path was correct according to previous answers for a Mac but the problem was simply that the **Genymotion plugin just needed to be updated**. I went to Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins > Genymotion and selected update (This is on a mac) and the problem went away after I updated the plugin and restarted Android Studio. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Great. The path was right and I had no clue. you were right! Thanks.

Comment: No problem glad I could be of help @madu

Answer (score 2):

What to do:

1. Open Genymotion itself (the round & pink icon on your desktop).

   2. Choose the "Settings" option from the upper menu.
   3. Choose the option "ADB" from the upper menu.
2. Select "Use Android custon SDK tools". Put the following path inside "Android SDK": C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion

   Why does it happen? you're getting the notice "You must specify a path to Genymotion folder to use this feature" because there's a bug in Genymotion working on Windows that misleads the Genymotion engine while trying to use the Android SDK.

Additional links:

[Can't find Genymotion.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658902/cant-find-genymotion-app)

Answer (score 2):

On a **Ubuntu**, you will find it here: */home/user/opt/genymobile/genymotion*

Answer (score 1):

For Linux system :

- though your genymotion is installed in "/usr/bin" folder its actually points to opt directory in root.
- Use following path in android studio for genymotion :
  `/opt/genymotion`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error after clicking installed plugin then, its asking the path of your installed Genymotion. So please provide path where your Genymotion is installed.

In my case it was **C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion**

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the way to solve the issue is the re-run the command

`sudo ./genymotion-x.x.x-linux_x64.bin`

in the directory where your bin file is located. For instance, suppose that I download the Genymotion .bin file to install Genymotion, and it's in the Downloads folder. I can move it to my home folder and run the following commands to install it.

`chmod +x genymotion-x.x.x-linux_x64.bin`

`sudo ./genymotion-x.x.x-linux_x64.bin`

After running those commands, you may run into an issue where the genymotion folder needed to specify the path does not get created. If you try pressing CTRL + h in the directory where your .bin is located, you will find a hidden folder called .Genymobile. The Genymotion folder will be inside of that folder. Even if you were to specify the path to that folder as `/home/<user>/.Genymobile/Genymotion`, you would still get the error. If you re-run the command `sudo ./genymotion-x.x.x-linux_x64.bin` where your .bin file is located, it will create the genymotion folder, and you can specify the path as `/home/<user>/genymotion` if the .bin file is located in your home directory. Once you specify the path, you can press ok, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, when I needed to add the Genymotion install dir to my `$PATH` environment variable on Mac OS X, I had to use the following path:

`/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS`

Answer (score 0):

Simply write

> C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion

It is the default path for the GennyMotion unless you have installed it somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

## To install Genymotion plugin for Android Studio:

1. In Android Studio, go to File/Settings (for Windows and Linux) or to Android Studio/Preferences (for Mac OS X)
2. Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
3. Right-click on Genymotion and click Download and install. To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar.

> ## ***To use this plugin, Genymotion must be installed on your system.***
>
> *Or download and install manually the plugin [genymotion-idea-plugin.jar](http://plugins.genymotion.com/plugins/idea/1.0.6/genymotion-idea-plugin-20150929.jar) (not recommended)*

**You have to give installed path of genymotion.**

[More Details You can Visit Official Genymotion Website.](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)