# Can't find Genymotion.app

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

I am unable to test my application on Android studio via genymotion.

Genymotion warning: You must specify the path to the Genymotion folder to use this feature.

when trying to location Genymotion.app I get this error: "Cannot find Genymotion in the specified path"

this is the path I entered for genymotion.app: 
C:\Users\Rua\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: You must specify a path to Genymotion folder to use this feuture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252690/android-studio-you-must-specify-a-path-to-genymotion-folder-to-use-this-feuture)

Comment: tried that..I still get the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252690/android-studio-you-must-specify-a-path-to-genymotion-folder-to-use-this-feature/62425876#62425876

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252690/android-studio-you-must-specify-a-path-to-genymotion-folder-to-use-this-feature/62425876#62425876

Answer (score 9):

On Mac,this is my solution:

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using Windows**

First off, you need to install Genymotion. Go to https://www.genymotion.com/#!/pricing and download and install it.

The default path is on Windows

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
```

And that's what you enter in the Android Studio prompt window.

**Using Mac**

Following [this](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/) tutorial, the default path on Mac seems to be

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app
```

Comment: I have already installed Genymotion, obviously. but I cant seem to find genymotion.app in the specified path.

Comment: "Genymotion.app" is a notation for Mac users. On windows you should find the Genymotion folder onto the path Marcus gave you: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion. Then enter it on Android Studio's settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed the Genymotion and VirtualBox, you can add

> /Applications/Genymotion.app

when you click *Genymotion Device Manager* in Android Studio.

Verified on MacBook Pro (OS X 10.11.6 EI CAPTAIN).

Answer (score -2):

if you are receiving this error that means that you do not have the genymotion app installed on your Mac

you can to download a .DMG file from [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) and install it by double clicking on it

you can try and run the installed app but it still won't run as it is missing the underlying virtual machine tool

to run genymotion you need virtualBox Guys at genymotion have mentioned their preferred choice as 4.3.12 which you can download from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3)

Once downloaded you can double click on the .DMG file and then the .pkg (package file) and then follow the normal installation procedure 
once you have the virtual box installed then you can run the genymotion app and you will get ***there was supposed to be an image here***

I was posting an image which would have helped you but SO says i need 10 reputation points to post images. then i decided to help you by posting an imgur url and SO says i need 10 reputations to post more than 2 links

kind request to SO either give me more reputation points or make it easy for me to help others

Now you Gennymotion is finally installed just go ahead and create a new virtual device
 and once you have created a new virtual device you can access that device from the Gennymotion Android Studio Plugin

Hope this helps