# Genymotion works well, but start Android Studio Plugin show error: 'unable to start VirtualBox'

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, android-studio-plugin

I've installed *Genymotion* and *VirtualBox* on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything goes fine. Genymotion works well.

Then I installed Genymotion Android Studio Plugin,but when I clicked 'start', it shows: unable to start VirtualBox

[image: unable to start VirtualBox]

Run Genymotion directly it works well, but Android Studio Plugin goes error,It is not like this: [Genymotion error at start 'Unable to load virtualbox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996901/genymotion-error-at-start-unable-to-load-virtualbox),how to fix it?

**Watch this,run genymotion directly works well, but run android studio plug it shows: 'unable to start virtualbox.'**[image]

Comment: @check the edited answer that will do the job for you. Didnt see that V.B coming

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have geni virtual box installed, install it.

*Your error says that you don't have your virtual box installed in your PC .*

*If you have then you have not given the right path click on geni icon and set path of it where You installed*

*(by default its like /Applications/Genymotion.app).you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252690/android-studio-you-must-specify-a-path-to-genymotion-folder-to-use-this-feature))*
[image]

Installing it on your pc won't be enough .You need to apply the plugin in android studio as well.

Go to *File>settings >(search for plugins in your left side)>select the option plugin > browse repositories > and install geni plugin* and you are good to go!

Restart android studio.

[image]

[image]

Finally if i missed anything watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw) for full thing

---

**Edit:If your are using a V.Box**

Go to **Network and Sharing Center** > **Change adapter settings** and enable these:

- Local Area Connection (if it's disabled)
- VirtualBox Host-Only Network

I think that enabling the second will do the job, but I did the first anyways.
read More details --------> [Unable to start Genymotion Virtual Device - Virtualbox Host Only Ethernet Adapter Failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106436/unable-to-start-genymotion-virtual-device-virtualbox-host-only-ethernet-adapte)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've installed VirtualBox,run Genymotion directly goes well, but start Android Studio Plugin show error: 'unable to start VirtualBox', :(

Comment: @xiaoxie have you set the path to geni from a.studio, i think that's the issue you haven't set the path and even its installed android studio cannot point where it is see my first image its need to be done after you add the plugin

Comment: click on that geni icon in your a.studio and set the path where you installed it so it will work

Comment: i have set the right path, see my second image,  the virtual devices list shows right(i create one virtual device in genymotion directly), but click to start shows error as the second image.

Comment: if every thing is okay are you ruining it on a virtual box?

Comment: yes, see my first image, every thing is okay when running on genymotion directly, but show errors through android studio plugin, it say 'unable to start virtualbox?', but genymotion works fine...

Comment: @xiaoxie change your settings as i said in my update. and for more you can go through that link as well, it should work :)

Comment: the vitual device works well through genymotion directly, but goes error through android studio plugin. and the error is 'unable to start virtualbox', not 'unable to start genymotion vitual device'. not like that link.

Comment: @xiaoxie  try this as well >http://stackoverflow.com/a/39271123/5188159

Comment: not like that link. i have updated question content and images. "run virtual device well through genymotion, but goes error through android studio plugin, i have set right path and plugin devices list is okay, but start error" :(

Comment: @xiaoxie last commented link is about geni with android studio,it says first run button to compile project and then...

Comment: it`s not like my problem, mine is: start virtual device well through genymotion, but start show error "unable to start virtualbox" through android studio plugin. if the virtualbox has some problem, genymotion should goes error, but it is okay! only through plugin to start show that error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open Genymotion -> Settings -> ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools -> locate your SDK.

You have to use the Genymotion SDK as that of Android studio.Try it hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling your current version of virtualbox and install Virtualbox version 5.0.28 from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0

Answer (score 0):

**The way around the error is to:**

1) Click on the Genymotion Device Manager in Android Studio. Once the Genymotion Device Manager window pops up, you will see your virtual device/devices, and its/their status should be "off".

[Genymotion Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCIih.png)

[Virtual Device Status is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPKR6.png)

2) Now, go run Genymotion outside of Android Studio.

3) In Genymotion, click on your virtual device to select it and click on the start button at the top left corner to start the virtual device.

4) Once your virtual device is up and running, go back to the Genymotion Device Manager window in Android Studio and click on refresh. You should see that the status of the virtual device is switched to "on". Now, you can run your code directly to Genymotion.